# Generating getters and setters in Doctrine without comments

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2 and Doctrine, so to create getters and setters methods I do:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities org/StoreBundle/Entity/Product
```

That works fine, but I would like to generate the getters and setters without comments. I think they are too obvious and redundant, for example:

```
    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    { 
        return $this->name;
    }
```

Five lines !
Is there any option to do that?

Comment: Although I respect you need to remove those phpdoc blocks but I urge you to think about it. Those are not as useful to you as they are pretty much priceless to your IDE. Especially if you have entities with relations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source for the Doctrine GenerateEntitiesCommand, it doesn't look like there is any way to do that: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php

However, why would you want to remove the comments? It's not like there is a line limit in PHP, and it is barely a blip on your compiling in terms of a performance hit for comments (the different is so small, there is no way you could actually measure it on your computer).

Also, if you use PHPDoc to generate documentation for your code, that @return string is more useful than you might thing, because you'd then know the return types for each of your getters (which isn't always very obvious).

Answer (score 4):

You may generate getter/setter using [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) IDE instead of Doctrine command line.

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer working using the command line, but you have given me an idea : find a script to generate getters and setters.